# Web Service main method

Tags: javascript, java, sql-server, web-services, jdeveloper

I need to publish a web service, but JDeveloper does not allow to publish static and main method.
How can I call this output again OR;
How can I publish the output of this code ? 
What kind of change do I need

```
package hr;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
public class DataHandler 
{
    public DataHandler() 
{
        super();
}
    public static void main (String[]   args )
{
           try
 {
            String url;
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@*****";
            Connection conn;
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"SIS****","****");
            Statement stmt;
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs;
               System.out.println ("oracle.db.open");
               rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM **** WHERE ****** ");
               while (rs.next())
{
              TABLE NAMES         
               }
               conn.close();
               System.out.println("oracle.db.close");
} 
               catch (SQLException e)
 {
               System.err.println("Error!!!");
                          System.err.println(e.getMessage());
```

Comment: `JDeveloper does not allow to publish static and main method`, well what exactly does it say

Comment: The static method main cannot be pubished in a web service.

Comment: btw you don't need to explicitly call the constructor of parent class if it has a no-args constructor therefore you can omit the `super` keyword

Comment: Can you tell us more about that web service? E.g. is it a servlet? In that case you need to do something with `doGet()` or `doPost()` methods. Initialization code would go to various context listeners.

Comment: This web service will publish the table data in xml format;so
I need to publish the output

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your code into a stand alone function (that is called from main), then try publishing the new function as a web service.